# Count the number of elements inside of a JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON string that represents a datatable with one row. Here's the table:

```
"MyData":[
    {
        "FirstName":"John",
        "LastName":"Doe",
        "ID":1234,
        "QCR3m":null,
        "FR3m":null,
        "ERI3m":null,
        "QCR6m":null,
        "FR6m":null,
        "ERI6m":null,
        "QCR1y":90.05,
        "FR1y":null,
        "ERI1y":93.55,
        "QCR3y":93.51,
        "FR3y":95.86,
        "ERI3y":94.0,
        "QCR5y":93.25,
        "FR5y":95.86,
        "ERI5y":94.0
    }
]
```

I want to count the number of columns in `MyData`. In this case the number would be 18. Is this possible to do in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Object.keys` with `length`

```js
var obj = {
        "FirstName":"John",
        "LastName":"Doe",
        "ID":1234,
        "QCR3m":null,
        "FR3m":null,
        "ERI3m":null,
        "QCR6m":null,
        "FR6m":null,
        "ERI6m":null,
        "QCR1y":90.05,
        "FR1y":null,
        "ERI1y":93.55,
        "QCR3y":93.51,
        "FR3y":95.86,
        "ERI3y":94.0,
        "QCR5y":93.25,
        "FR5y":95.86,
        "ERI5y":94.0
    };

console.log(Object.keys(obj).length);
```